# how validate unique email and unique name in update laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

This is my code:

```
public function update(User $user)
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'name'   => 'required|min:3|max:50|unique:users,name,' . $user->id,
        'email'  => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email,' . $user->id,
        'origin' => 'max:50',
        'about'  => 'max:5000',
    ]);
    $user = User::find($user);
    $user->name = request('name');
    $user->original = request('origin');
    $user->email = request('email');
    $user->about = request('about');
    $user->save();

    return back();
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: select * from .... ?))
```

Comment: Thanks,  I deleted this line $user = User::find($user); and solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error probably stems from `$user = User::find($user);`.

Since you're using [Route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding) you shouldn't need to load the `User` again:

```
public function update(User $user)
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'name'   => 'required|min:3|max:50|unique:users,name,' . $user->id,
        'email'  => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email,' . $user->id,
        'origin' => 'max:50',
        'about'  => 'max:5000',
    ]);

    $user->name = request('name');
    $user->original = request('origin');
    $user->email = request('email');
    $user->about = request('about');
    $user->save();

    return back();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Validate function expect first parameter as request input array not a request object. The following code will work fine.

`$this->validate (request()->all(), $rules)`

You can also pass third parameter for validation messages.

Comment: `$this->validate(...)` in a controller expects the first param to be an instance of `\Illuminate\Http\Request`.